# Questions integrating new Groovy template engine with Spring MVC and Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, groovy, spring-security, spring-boot

As blogged on spring.io both Spring 4.1 and Sprig Boot will integrate the new Groovy template engine (https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/28/using-the-innovative-groovy-template-engine-in-spring-boot, http://spring.io/blog/2014/07/28/spring-framework-4-1-spring-mvc-improvements).

I wonder the following:

- Will Spring provide something like it does with the Spring Forms and Spring Security taglib?
- If not what would be best to e.g. render form fields and more importantly form errors?

I think without it it will be a step back to develop a traditional Spring MVC webapp.

The template engine suports something like a BaseTemplate (see http://mrhaki.blogspot.nl/2014/08/groovy-goodness-use-custom-template.html) where it would be possible to provide custom methods to the template engine.

Related to this:

- You can only provdide a single base template, so it will be difficult to include methods from multiple extension points. E.g. Spring Forms, Spring Security and multiple custom extensions like Fontawesome.
- Is it possible to set the base template with Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to expose a lot of the spring specific attributes `csrf` etc... is to include `spring.groovy.template.expose-request-attributes = true` in your `application.properties`